# Getting exception in intellij ide for, flutter demo app hello_services

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

```
Exception from flutter run: Exception: Unable to locate Gradle. Please configure the path to Gradle using `flutter config --gradle-dir`.
package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart 31              throwToolExit
package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart 115          buildGradleProject.<async>
dart:async/future.dart 184                                 Future.Future.microtask.<fn>
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 185  StackZoneSpecification._run
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 97   StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.<fn>
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 185  StackZoneSpecification._run
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 97   StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1146                                  _rootRun
dart:async/zone.dart 1026                                  _CustomZone.run
dart:async/zone.dart 924                                   _CustomZone.runGuarded
dart:async/zone.dart 951                                   _CustomZone.bindCallback.<fn>
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 185  StackZoneSpecification._run
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 97   StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.<fn>
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 185  StackZoneSpecification._run
package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart 97   StackZoneSpecification._registerCallback.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1150                                  _rootRun
dart:async/zone.dart 1026                                  _CustomZone.run
dart:async/zone.dart 924                                   _CustomZone.runGuarded
dart:async/zone.dart 951                                   _CustomZone.bindCallback.<fn>
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 41                      _microtaskLoop
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 50                      _startMicrotaskLoop
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 96                   _runPendingImmediateCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 149                  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
```

If I run flutter config in the terminal, flutter command not found exception is thrown in the terminal.

Comment: did you do any modification or you directly try the folder inside flutter/exemple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code which tries to find gradle:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/gradle.dart#L37

The `flutter` command is located inside the `bin` directory of the flutter SDK you downloaded.  Adding it to your path is covered in our setup docs: https://flutter.io/setup/#get-the-flutter-sdk

You can specify the location of your gradle binary using args to the commands or globally using `flutter config` with the `--gradle-dir` or `--android-studio-dir` flags.

As you can see in the linked code, we know how to find gradle in some default locations, such as inside `/Applications/Android Studio.app` or by reading your path variable.  We probably could add more default locations.

If you believe your Android SDK is installed in a default location we're not checking please file a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new and we're happy to fix.

Comment: , can u please tell how to navigate between dart and android activities